# R.script not executing in osx crontab

Tags: r, cron

I am trying to run an Rscript in crontab on OS X (10.11.5) and I have not been able to get it to execute.  The script permission are working and the path is working.  I have blacked out some of the file path

here is the crontab job, the script name is h2oDeepLearnCRON.R

```
20 5 * * 0-4 /bin/bash /Users/#########/#######/FinancialMarketModeling/h2oDeepLearnCRON.R >> testrun.txt
```

I get the following mail message outlining the error

```
X-Cron-Env: <SHELL=/bin/sh>
X-Cron-Env: <PATH=/usr/bin:/bin>
X-Cron-Env: <LOGNAME=#######>
X-Cron-Env: <USER=#######>
X-Cron-Env: <HOME=/Users/#######>
Date: Wed,  1 Feb 2017 05:20:01 -0500 (EST)

/Users/#######/########/FinancialMarketModeling/h2oDeepLearnCRON.R: line 7: syntax error near unexpected token `quantmod'
/Users/#########/#######/FinancialMarketModeling/h2oDeepLearnCRON.R: line 7: `require(quantmod)'
```

the program starts to execute but generates an error when it encounters the first line of code which is loading the packages

```
require(quantmod)
```

I have done some searching on the shell not recognizing the the "("  and recommended the script have a

```
#!/bin/bash
```

inserted, but that did not work nothing happened

Any suggestions would be helpful

Is this the revised suggestion?

```
 20 5 * * 0-4 Rscript.R  /Users/#########/#######/FinancialMarketModeling/h2oDeepLearnCRON.R
```

Comment: What do you actually mean by `The script permission are working and the path is working`? Are you trying to execute an R script directly in `bash`? That will not work. You need to run Rscript or R with the name of the script..

Comment: I know the permission was working because I had to to use a chop u+x in an earlier step the that was generating a permission denied error and that went away.  the second part, executing may be a misinterpretation on my part because i saw part of my code in the output.

Comment: is your suggestion the following code added above

Comment: another approach would be use `/bin/bash` and call a `start.sh` file which contains `Rscript your.R`

Comment: Bhas,  Thanks,  I tried the above interpretation, is my revised crontab what you intended? it did not run successfully

Comment: I don't know anything about crontab. But where does `Rscript.R` come from? There is  only  `R` and `Rscript`. I'm not surprised it didn't run successfully.